# How to save application state in Marathon?

Tags: docker, vagrant, mesos, marathon

I have a vagrant machine and I am running Mesos and Marathon over it, I am launching an app in Marathon that app is a docker container.

When I do vagrant halt and again do vagrant up my marathon and mesos service gets started but my docker app stops. So is there a way I can save the app state and get the app started as soon as vagrant goes up?